# "Don't require authentication" open is disabled while sending Survey through email invitation

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, survey, salesforce-survey

I have created a Survey. I have been trying to share the Survey without Authentication to external network. I can do it by using "Get Invitation" link. However when I try to do the same using Send Email option, I see the "Don't require authentication" option being disabled.

I even tried to add the survey page to the community page but it shows the error "This is placeholder. Survey don't run in canvas"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the survey's standard functionality. The "Don't require authentication" is dependent on the recipient that you have selected. When sending a survey email from survey builder it is expected that you no longer require authentication as you are manually selecting the right contact or user to send to.

From my observation, the behavior of the "Don't require authentication" checkbox is that for

1. Lead records (orange icon) - default checked, grayed out
2. User records (blue icon) - default unchecked, grayed out
3. Contact records (purple icon) - default unchecked, could be manually changed